# Discord.py music bot doesn't play music after being manually disconnected

Tags: discord, discord.py

I made a discord.py music bot that can execute such commands as play, skip, pause, resume, now, stop, loop, leave, etc. However, I stuck with one problem. When my bot disconnects by executing the command leave or manually disconnects after timing out, everything works fine, but after I disconnect it manually by the discord way (RMB → Disconnect) and try to play something, it just joins my voice channel and doesn't play anything, though when I execute "now" command, it shows me the requested song. That's pretty strange, in my opinion.
I tried to mess around a little:

```
@bot.event
    async def on_disconnect(self, ctx: commands.Context):
        ctx.voice_state.songs.clear()
        await ctx.voice_state.stop()
        del self.voice_states[ctx.guild.id]
```

Unfortunately, it didn't work.

Is there any solution?